# WPMU Dev Humminbird Pro and Smush and Cloudflare

Tags: plugins, cloudflare

It seems to me that most (if not all) functions which WPMU Dev plugins Hummingbird Pro (site optimization for speed) and Smush (image optimization) can be achieved with Cloudflare paid account. Is there any reason to have those two plugins together with Cloudflare?

Comment: That's something to ask their various support teams.